# how to get the cssText of external style?

Tags: javascript, css

I have tried hours to get the results, but failed, below, I will post all I have done, hope I can get some tips, BTW,Thanks.

from the error message, yeah It's *cssRules* is null, surely error!

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en">
  <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
  <title>css style</title>
  <style type="text/css">
     #demo {
        font-size: 10px;    /*first css rule */ 
     }
     p {
        border: 1px solid green;  /*second one*/
     }
      </style>
    </head>
   <body>
   <div id="demo" style="color: red;">
   <p>how to access of document's css!</p>
  </div>
 </body>
```

external css

```
    #demo {
         font-weight: 900;
      }
     p {
         padding: 20px;
    }
```

Javascript

```
   <script>
      /*1,to get the inline style, this maybe the most easy one*/
      var cssInline = document.getElementById('demo').style;
      var cssInText = cssInline.cssText, cssColor = cssInline.color;
      console.log(cssInText, cssColor);

      /*2.a to get the style in head*/
      var cssInHeada = document.getElementById('demo');
      // using the computed css of inline
      var cssHeadText = getComputedStyle(cssInHeada, null);
      console.log(cssHeadText);

      // 2.b to get the style directly
      var cssInHeadb = document.getElementsByTagName('style')[0];
      console.log(cssInHeadb.textContent);

     // 2.c or like this
     var cssInHeadc = document.styleSheets[1];
     console.log(cssInHeadc.cssRules[0].cssText); //per rule

     /*3, but I cant get the extenal style*/
     var cssExtenal = document.styleSheets[0];
     console.log(cssExtenal.cssRules[0].cssText);
     </script>
```

Thank your guys!

Comment: If everything fails you can try to fetch the css using ajax.

Comment: @jcbic Thanks, I am newbie of Javascript , I do't handle the ajax by now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect your JavaScript is running before the stylesheet is loaded. Try this:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
  var cssExtenal = document.styleSheets[0];
  console.log(cssExtenal.cssRules[0].cssText);
}, false);
```

Or if you happen to be using jQuery, this is more universal:

```
$('document').ready(function(){
  var cssExtenal = document.styleSheets[0];
  console.log(cssExtenal.cssRules[0].cssText);
});
```

**Update**: another possibility is that you're using Chrome and either loading the CSS cross-domain or using the `file://` protocol. [This appears to be a known issue and is not considered a bug.](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=49001)

Comment: Thanks for your help. I just put all js before </body>! and this will be run before the stylesheet is loaded? and after trying your code (copy it), error stiil **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of null**

Comment: Are you loading the CSS cross-domain or with the file:// protocol? See my updated answer, and try loading all resources through a web server.

Comment: both file:// protocol & online has the same result. I've tested it

Comment: @HermanNz  you can get the external css text with above codes or not?

Comment: @JeremiahOrr yeah, both are right. It's chrome and also file:// protocol!

Comment: @JeremiahOrr I get the result by using FF and file://protocol. Thank you so much

Comment: @Tab I did. It really worked on me in both protocol (file:// and http) see here: http://prntscr.com/9shre4

Comment: @Tab are you saying that the problem is solved? If so, you might want to mark this answer as the solution (click the green checkmark).

Comment: @JeremiahOrr Thank you, it works in FF now!,but not Chrome!

Comment: @Tab I suggest not using the file:// protocol, then. Just fire up a simple web server. For example, on OS X, try "python -m SimpleHTTPServer" in the appropriate directory.

Comment: @JeremiahOrr Thanks for your suggest, I have set up a web server with nginx on ubuntu, later I will try this!